# ¿Cómo restar días a una fecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

He estado buscando y la solución que encontré me da error me sale que el check.getDate no es una función.
Este es mi código donde recoge el día donde hago click en un fullcalendar.

```
        var check = info.dateStr;
        check = Date.parse(check)
        var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
        var days = ["0","01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"];
        var today =  new Date();
        today = today.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+months[today.getUTCMonth()]+"-"+days[today.getUTCDate()];
        check = check.setDate(check.getDate() - limite)
        alert(check);
       if( check < today )
        {
          Swal.fire(
            'Vaya parece que llegas tarde',
            'Deberias selecionar una fecha disponible',
            'error'
          )
        }
```

Donde limite es una variable que tengo global con un valor de 3

Comment: Hola, no se si te es posible que la agregues en el proyecto pero por si acaso te dejo una librería buena para eso: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: puedes probar esto `check.getTime() < today.getTime()` para saber que la fecha `check` es menor. Comenta esto primero  `today = today.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+months[today.getUTCMonth()]+"-"+days[today.getUTCDate()];`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/parse) te retorna un entero con la fecha en milisegundos transcurridos desde 1970.

```js
var check = "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT";
check = Date.parse(check)
console.log(check)
```

mientras que [`.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDate) es una función de una instancia de `Date`

```js
var check = 'Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT';
check = new Date(check)
console.log(check.getDate())
```

Estuve tratando de corregir tu código y en realidad me encontré con otros errores. Creo que por un tema de limpieza de código, y para no reinventar la rueda (probablemente tu código no maneje años bisiestos, cambio de zona horaria, entre otras excepciones que tiene el manejo de fechas), deberías usar [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
const limite = 3
let today = moment()
let check = moment('25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT').subtract(limite, 'days')
console.log(check, today, check.isBefore(today));
// En caso que sea un fecha en el futuro
check = moment('25 Dec 2021 13:30:00 GMT').subtract(limite, 'days')
console.log(check, today, check.isBefore(today));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para restar días podes utilizar la función getTime() que pasa la fecha a milisegundos
y luego volves a convertir la fecha en string, espero te sirva.

```js
//RESTAR FECHAS

var fecha1 = new Date(2020, 02, 03).getTime() ;

var fecha2 = new Date(2020, 02, 04).getTime() ;

var auxiliar = fecha2 - fecha1;

var res = fecha2 - auxiliar;

res = new Date(res).toString();
console.log(res);

//RESTAR DIAS A UNA FECHA

 var fecha1 = new Date(2020, 02, 03).getTime() ;

var dia = 1;
//paso el dia a segundos
dia = 1*24*60*60
var res = fecha1 - dia;
res = new Date(res).toString();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Veo que restas fechas , pero no que a una fecha X le restes 45 dias...